# Alfresco basic authentication works with curl but not with python

Tags: python, alfresco

I am having a problem with authentication error from Alfresco, maybe somebody could enlighten me while im trying to find log files from the mess that is Alfresco.

```
curl -uadmin:password -X POST https://hostname/alfresco/api/-default-/public/alfresco/versions/1/nodes/node_uuid/children -F filedata=@/home/user/file.pdf
```

Now when I am trying to use python requests(TM) it gives me a 401. Ive checked the requests and they both send the same Authentication hash

This is the python code:

```
def handle_row_for_request(row):

    url = 'https://' + hostname + '/alfresco/api/-default-/public/alfresco/versions/1/nodes/' + base_uuid + '/children'

    data = '/home/user/file.pdf'

    with open(data, 'rb') as payload:
        headers={"content-type": "multipart/form-data"}
        response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload, auth=(username, password))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the `data` argument, but you need to use the [`file` argument](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file):

```
def handle_row_for_request(row):

    url = 'https://' + hostname + '/alfresco/api/-default-/public/alfresco/versions/1/nodes/' + base_uuid + '/children'

    files = {'filedata': ('/home/user/file.pdf', open('/home/user/file.pdf', 'rb'))}
    headers={"content-type": "multipart/form-data"}
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, files=files, auth=(username, password))
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the Python code which works fine for the upload which also uses the basic auth. Please check the request params.

```
import json
import requests

url = "http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/api/upload"
auth = ("admin", "admin")
files = {"filedata": open("/tmp/foo.txt", "rb")}
data = {"siteid": "test", "containerid": "documentLibrary"}
r = requests.post(url, files=files, data=data, auth=auth)
print(r.status_code)
print(json.loads(r.text))
```

Comment: https://hub.alfresco.com/t5/alfresco-content-services-forum/upload-file-with-properties-multiple-value/td-p/166183

Comment: ```Re: Upload file with properties (multiple value)
For reference, can you please confirm your Alfresco version ? 

If you're using 5.2+, which REST API / url:

* V0 => POST .../alfresco/s/api/upload

* V1 => POST .../alfresco/api/-default-/public/alfresco/versions/1/nodes/{parentid}/children

Thanks,

Jan```

Answer (score 0):

There were 2 parts to the problem. First I needed to use the file argument instead of data. On top of that Alfresto wants to get 'filedata' string inside the file argument.

Secondly auth(user,pw) generated a hash that had a single = sign in the end and alfresco said 401. When I used cURL and got the password hash from there it had two = signs in the end. Weird right? But that worked. Instead of using auth(user,pw) I set the 'Authorization': 'Basic ${base64thing}' as the authentication.

````py
response = requests.post(url, headers={'Authorization': 'Basic base64string'}, files={'filedata': open(/path/, 'rb')})```
````